# Callback Functions inside the Cordova.exec with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript

i have a problem with TypeScript Definition for Cordova.

The codrova.d.ts file allows for success-callback and error-callback no function arguments.

for a better understanding of my problem a little example:

Thats the original code of the cordova.d.ts file

```
exec(success: () => any, fail: () => any, service: string, action: string, args?: string[]): void;
```

now i want to write a class in typescript like this structure

```
module Plugin { 

export class {

constructor(){
cordova.exec(this.success,this.error,"Service","Action",null);
}

private success(message:string)
{
   //do Something
}

private error(message:string)
{
   //do Something
}
```

Now i got a error in the line of the cordova.exec call with the message, that the function signature of success and error match like this (message:string)=>void and ()=>any are not compatible.

My Question is, how can i use callback arguments to give a more detailed information to the platform independend side if a call was successfull or not.

Or is it a mistake inside the cordova.d.ts operation?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quick Fixes

There are a few fixes you need to your example code...

```
module Example {

    class Test {

        constructor() {
            cordova.exec(this.success, this.error, "Service", "Action", null);
        }

        private success() {
            //do Something
        }

        private error() {
            //do Something
        }
    }
}
```

This passes the definition for Cordova.

If you suspect this is wrong and both `success` and `error` may actually take a string, you could make them optional and it would still pass the existing type check:

```
private success(message?: string) {
    //do Something
}
```

## Proper Fixes

Of course, if the type definition is wrong, you can update it with the correct definitions and submit it back to the Definitely Typed project...

```
exec(success: Function,
    fail: (message: string) => any,
    service: string,
    action: string,
    args?: string[]): void;
```

I have different suggested fixes here, based on an assumption... the success function will be passed something specific on success, perhaps a message or an object (who knows what). The fail function will be passed a string message.